# Did the policy on ordering of questions change?

Tags: support

I noticed recently that questions go to the top of the queue (under Questions link) whenever an edit is made to any of the answers, or when there is a new answer. But then they quickly disappear from there. This seems different from before, when only newly asked questions would go to the top of the queue. Did the policy change and what exactly is the new one? For example, does it affect all questions, no matter how old, what determines how long they stay at the top, are there any requirements on edits that trigger it, does it apply to new comments, or just question and answer edits, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the home page (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) and the questions page (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions). On the latter, only new questions cause updates. On the former, any 'activity' causes updates:

- New question
- New answer
- Edit to question
- Edit to answer

Status changes (closed/reopened/protected/unprotected/locked/...) do not cause updates, nor do comments.

---

At least, all this is if you keep the default ordering:

[image]

On the right, you can choose different orderings. You can do the same on /questions, but with different options.

Comment: The questions page behaved  oddly between September 5 and 9. Perhaps I accidentally clicked "active", or there was a glitch, or... Anyway, it stopped now.